# UWP App is going to suspended state despite of active connection and request received handler executing

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am currently working on UWP application. This App needs to communicate even when app is closed.

So, I am using `AppServiceConnection` for the same. I open an `AppServiceConnection` and it invokes `OnBackgroundActivated` of App. I store this connection and add request received handler in the app's one class object and I also initialize few object to perform some task when request received handler is called.

When other .exe sends message to UWP app using app service connection after opening the connection, then request received handler is called. I take deferral on request received handler also.

Inside `RequestReceived` handler, I need to call a method of class which was being instantiated on opening connection. But by the time, I go to that statement in `RequestReceived` handler to call that method.

App goes to suspended state. Hence object is no longer is there in memory.

Now, I have few question.

1. If I have taken deferral on App `ReqeustRecevied` handler, then App should not go into suspended state.
   is it correct assumption? or It doesn't really matter.
2. Once App is about to get in suspended state as then I request extend session using 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution

   but my request access is getting denied every time.

Could anybody explaination for above two points and would appreciate if can provider better solution.

Code Sample

// Main UWP App class

```
    public sealed partial class App : Application, IDisposable
    {

     protected async override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);



          var taskDeferral =  arg.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
        if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is AppServiceTriggerDetails details &&
            details.CallerPackageFamilyName == Package.Current.Id.FamilyName)
        {
            AppServiceConnectionHelper.Connection = (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails).AppServiceConnection;
            IntializeNonUICommunciaiton(args);
            var instanceToHandleRequest = new HandleRequestReceivedClass();
            AppServiceConnectionHelper.Connection += instanceToHandleRequest.OnRequestReceived;
        }

    }
```

}

```
=======================================
  public Class HandleRequestReceivedClass
   {
       List<MessageHandler> handlers =new List<MessageHandler>();

    public async void OnBridgeClientPluginMessage(AppServiceConnection 
      sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
         handlers[args.Request.Message](); // app goes to suspended state and  
         can't find handler which are delegate defined in the app.
         }
        finally
         {
             messageDeferral.complete();
          }             
    }
```

Comment: If you get the deferral, it should not suspend. Could you add some code snippets so we can see more clearly?